# Dockerfile - copying a bash file from host to Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to copy a bash file called `setup_envs.sh` which is in the same directory of my Dockerfile.

How can I run this bash file **only once** after Dockerfile is created?

My code is (in the end of the Dockerfile):

```
RUN mkdir -p /scripts
COPY setup_env.sh /scripts
WORKDIR /scripts
RUN chmod +x /scripts/setup_env.sh
CMD [./scripts/setup_env.sh]
```

**Current error:**
`/bin/bash: [./scripts/setup_env.sh]: No such file or directory`

I don't have a type in the file btw, I checked this.

Moreover, after I solve this and run the image to create a container - how can I make sure this bash script is only called once? Should I just write a command in the bash script that checks if some folder exists - and if it does - don't install it?

Comment: looks like you set the `WORKDIR` to `/scripts`, which is where your `setup_env.sh` is located. You probably want `CMD [./setup_env.sh]` to use a relative path or `CMD [/scripts/setup_env.sh]` to use an absolute path

Comment: By the nature of a containers when you run the image the command in `CMD` will be run to completion and the container stopped and so will only ever be run once unless you open an interactive shell to the container while the script is still running. If you *really* need to prevent multiple runs creating an empty file as you suggest should work well for most circumstances

Comment: Also either `CMD` needs to be a proper JSON array with quotes `CMD ["/scripts/setup_env.sh"]` or a plain-text shell command without brackets `CMD /scripts/setup_env.sh`.  This `CMD` will be the _only_ thing the container runs and when it completes the container will exit; from the name of the script that might not be the effect you want.

Comment: `RUN mkdir -p /scripts` <= this is useless and creates an unnecessary layer. You can do that job at once by slightly changing your copy instruction => `COPY setup_env.sh /scripts/`. This will create the directory if it does not exist and copy the file inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the different comments including mine, this is what your `Dockerfile` extract should be replaced with:

```
COPY --chmod 755 setup_env.sh /scripts/
WORKDIR /scripts
CMD /scripts/setup_env.sh
```

Alternatively you can use the exec form for `CMD` but there is not much added value here since you're not passing any command line parameters.

```
CMD ["/scripts/setup_env.sh"]
```

At this point, I'm not really sure the `WORKDIR` instruction is useful (it depends on the rest of your `Dockerfile` and the content of your script).

Regarding your single bash script execution, I think you need to give a bit more background on the exact goal you are targeting. I have the feeling you could be in an [X/Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info). And since this is a totally different issue, it should go inside a new question anyway with all required details.

Comment: you can copy with the chmod option `COPY --chmod 755 setup_env.sh /scripts/`

Comment: @the fool: you can edit answers to make them better. Yes I missed that one.